# how to insert same ID on dropdown choice

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to have 3 tables Category Subcategory and CatOption

- Name of table: `Category` columns: `Id, Category`
- Name of table: `Subcategory` Columns: `id, cat_id, sub`
- Name of table: `CatOption` columns: `id ,sub_id, caption`

I created 3 drop down list who are fetching data based on ID

Now I need to insert data in that tables so it can look like this
example

```
Category 1 Sky
Subcategory 1 1(copy from category id) Blue
Subcategory 2 1 (copy from category id) Grey
CatOption 1 1 (copy from subcategory id) sunny
CatOption 2 1 (copy from subcategory id) with clouds
```

These values are just for example user will insert all data

**EDIT**: I was wondering I had one idea can I base my search on category  name not id so under cat_id I would have category like in the example below

```
Category 1 Sky
Subcategory 1 Sky (copy from category) Blue
Subcategory 2 Sky (copy from category) Grey
CatOption 1 Blue (copy from subcategory) sunny
CatOption 2 Blue (copy from subcategory) with clouds
```

Comment: If you want the menus to change while the user is selecting, without submitting the form, you need to do this in client-side JavaScript.

Comment: yes I Have that but how to insert it to the table?

Comment: After you insert a category, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will contain the ID that was created by `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Use that for the `cat_id` when inserting into `Subcategory`. And after you insert into `Subcategory`, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will contain that ID, which you can use when inserting into `CatOption`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 3 functions to insert, 1 for Category 1 for Subcategory and 1 for catOption. On the Category function you do something like $_SESSION['id'] = $last_entry. Then on the Subcategory you pass the category id as something like $catId = $data['id'] and do the same for catOption. Sorry if it's too messy. Also on the form page you should have $id_category = $_Session['id']

Comment: as I understand  $last_entry is last entry ID but what if i have other category and some entries for that one and again I need to come back to the sky it will copy ID from other category? My only idea is to have a drop down list who will fetch data from category and what ever category i choose to copy that ID to other table?

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain it better?

Comment: $last_entry statement is to copy last ID and if more than  category i Category table I need them to have different ID but in the second table I will have more subcategories who will be under different category